# Find the degree of a splitting field.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

> Let $F$ be a splitting field for $x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, find $[F:\mathbb{Z}_3]$.

I'm not sure how to proceed in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, I guess the situation is quite different than with polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried factoring the polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I was working on it, but then I realised that if I get, let's say that $x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 = (ax^2 + bx + c)(dx^ + ex + f)$, I'm still lost. Also one OT question - how did you spotlight that important part of my post?

Comment: Just use this character: >. Also, the polynomial has a root in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, which makes the factoring easier.

Comment: Hint: Your polynomial is equal to $(x+1)(x^3+2x+1)$, and $x^3+2x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The situation is a little easier in finite fields : if we have the irreducible factorization $f(x) =\prod_j f_j(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ then the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ where $k=lcm(deg(f_j))$

Comment: So splitting field of my polynomial will be $\mathbb{Z}_{27}?$, I'm even more confused now.

Comment: No. The splitting field will be $\Bbb{F}_{27}$.